# Oracle: conditionally run a SELECT within a WITH clause

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

We have a fairly lengthy stored proc (Oracle 12) that contains as series of WITH clauses that build on one another in this fashion:

```
WITH temp1 AS (SELECT ... FROM tableA WHERE ...),
WITH temp2 AS (SELECT ... FROM temp1, tableB WHERE ...),
WITH temp3 AS (SELECT ... FROM temp2, tableC WHERE ...),
```

with a final SELECT being done from the temp3 entity

```
SELECT ... FROM temp3;
```

This works but recently we've been asked to 'bookend' the final select so that it has a dummy first row, and a dummy last row. Ie if 'temp3' contains three rows then the final SELECT would return 5 rows including the two dummy rows. However if temp3 contains no data then the two dummy rows should not appear either and user gets back an empty record set.

How could we go about bookending the final select if temp3 contains data, but return an empty recordset if temp3 has now rows?

Comment: Perhaps insert the two bookend rows unconditionally (with a `UNION ALL` clause), but then filter them again if the total row count is just 2?

Comment: Does your query work as written, with the keyword WITH repeated before each factored subquery? I kind of doubt that.

Comment: Are the dummy rows hard-coded? Or do they depend on data from any of the factored subqueries? (Other than the fact that they should only be added if temp3 is non-empty.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
with temp1 as ( . . . ),
     temp2 as ( . . . ),
     temp3 as ( . . . )
select t
from (select dummyrow1 from dual union all
      select . . . from temp3 union all
      select dummyrow2 from dual
     ) t
where exists (select 1 from temp3);
```

If you care about the ordering of the rows, then you should include an `order by` in the outermost `select`.